How do I read the model results summary of statsmodels vecm to build the VEC equation?
I have been working on building a VEC model to forecast a dependent Y using multiple independent variables whose future values are a given using statsmodels in python.
I wanted to know if this made sense, since a YouTube video I checked out said it was only possible for endogenous variable VAR system, and my independent variables in this case should act as exogenous variables. In this case how should I go about building the model? I am currently using them in the exog_coint parameter.
I also wanted to know how to interpret the model.summary() results from the statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECM package. Supposing I have 1 Y variable and 3 X variables, with a cointegration rank of 3 and lag order 3- then how do I manually construct the model results of the model?
I assume it goes like this- Y_t = SUM(Coeff_Xi * Xi_t) + SUM(LagCoeff_Xi_t-j * Xi_t-j) + SUM(LagCoeff_Y_tj* Y_tj) + ec_1(beta_1 * Y_t + beta_2 * X_1 ...) + now what though? How do I interpret the ec_2 and ec_3 for my equation for Y_t?
